# Azure monitoring Data Collection Rules(DCR) through DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-monitoring

A monitoring agent can be installed through powershell. But DCR is required after that
How can we deploy DCR through DevOps?

Comment: There is a REST API documented for this, with a sample DCR in the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collection-rule-overview. Is it therefore not just a REST request from DevOps to create the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data collection rules currently support the following input sources:

Azure virtual machine with the Azure Monitor agent.

> There are currently two available methods to create a DCR:
>
> - Use the Azure portal to create a data collection rule and have it    associated with one or more virtual machines.
> - Directly edit the data collection rule in JSON and submit using the    [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/datacollectionrules).
>
> [*Source Link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collection-rule-overview#create-a-dcr)

Azure DevOps Service side do not provide any build-in solution or extension/task to handle this. You may have to use JSON and REST API as mentioned above.

Comment: Did u mean rest API task as Dylan mentioned?

Comment: Similar, but we do not have rest API task in Azure DevOps. You could write you own application to involve Rest API to create a DCR in build agent(Azure virtual machine).